# handlerInput.responseBuilder returns before I can fetch data from an observable

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, alexa-skills-kit

I am getting my data for an alexa skill from an observable, the problem I'm facing is that the response to alexa is sent before I can fetch that data.

I am working with ask cli and nodejs

```
const GetReminderIntentHandler = {
   canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest' && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'GetReminderIntent';
   },
  handle(handlerInput) {
    let speechText = "";
    data
    .subscribe(data=>{

        entities = data.Entities;
        entities.forEach(entity => {
            med = entity.Text;
            attributes = entity.Attributes;
            attributes.forEach(attribute=>{
                if(attribute['Type']=='DOSAGE')
                    dosage = attribute['Text'];
                if(attribute['Type']=='FREQUENCY')
                    freq = attribute['Text'];
            })
            response.push({
                medicineName:med,
                dosage:dosage,
                frequency:freq
            })
        });
        speechText = response[0].medicineName;
        //Just a mock use case, still have to restructure the data a bit
    }, err =>{
      speechText = err;
    })

     return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .speak(speechText)
    .withSimpleCard('Reminder', speechText)
    .getResponse();

    }

  },
};
```

The result comes out to be just an empty string. I need a way to wait for the observable to get the data in the array "response" before sending "speechText" to Alexa.

Comment: what is the return value of `handle`, an observable?

Comment: Hey Veer, the problem is Node operates your code asynchronous so it working on building your response at the same time it's resolving your attributes. There are numerous ways to address this. Promises, using async and await. Here is a good reference to read https://developer.amazon.com/fr/blogs/alexa/post/4a46da08-d1b8-4d8e-9277-055307a9bf4a/alexa-skill-recipe-update-call-and-get-data-from-external-apis and a number of good video tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ze6krw1W-mg

Answer (score 0):

Your handle should be `async handle` and `await data.subscribe` should be async as well. To make that, you need to use promises inside data.subscribe.

Doing that your utterance will wait until request is ready.